# Python json import 'module' object has no attribute 'loads'

Tags: python, json, pyscripter

I'm using PyScripter on Windows with Python 2.7.3 and I'm trying to import json.  It seems to work if I use the interpreter directly, but when saved in a file and run I get 'module' object has no attribute 'loads'.

```
import json

j = '{"one": 1, "numbers": [1, 2, 3.5]}'

x = json.loads(j)
```

Interpreter for x returns, `{u'numbers': [1, 2, 3.5], u'one': 1}`

I'm fairly new to Python so I'm sorry if this is an idiotic question.  Many thanks

Comment: One possible reason: You might have called your own file json.py.

Comment: Thanks Matthias that worked.  I also had delete the file that I'd created from the same directory because it was trying to import that back in.  I feel like a fool but I've got to learn some how...  thanks again

Comment: Is there any reason you're using Python 2.7.3 instead of 2.7.6? I know it's a minor version difference, but it's best to keep up with updates for security and bug fixes.

Comment: @Matthias You should write that as an answer.

Comment: @Bakuriu: I'm not a reputation hunter. :-)